# Do I need to verify a AWS Cognito token in BOTH Lambda AND as API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

When using a AWS Cognito attribute from a JWT token in a lambda, do I need to verify the JWT? The Lambda is only triggered by an API Gateway which already verifies the token.

Adding details: 
 - I'm using Cognito Authorizer in the API Gateway to verify the token. 
 - The lambda is connected to the API Gateway as proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to verify the JWT in backend lambda if protected by a [custom lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-types) by API Gateway. I would suggest you to use REQUEST based lambda authorizer and attach [attributes in the response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html). So your backend lambda will be able to access attributes in `event.requestContext.authorizer['your_attribue']`.

This will also enable you to test your Lambda in isolation without needing to get attribute from JWT. You can always mock the `event` object for unit testing.

Comment: thanks. I use cognito authorizer, not custom lambda authorizer in the API GW, does that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry I just assumed you are using custom authorizor because you mentioned JWT. As far as I am aware when using IAM_ROLE based authorization caller submit access keys or perhaps submit signed request. Regardless your lambda integration don’t need to validate user making request.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same conundrum, and was trying to find **documented** confirmation that, within the Lambda, I wouldn't have to do any validation on my own, and that I can safely rely on the the token / claims being genuine. Unfortunately, nothing in the AWS documentation or the forum posts that I've seen so far has *explicitly* confirmed this.

But I did find something similar for GCP, and how the API Gateway there validates the JWT. From the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt):

> To authenticate a user, a client application must send a JSON Web
> Token (JWT) in the authorization header of the HTTP request to your
> backend API. API Gateway validates the token on behalf of your API, so
> ***you don't have to add any code in your API to process the
> authentication.*** However, you do need to configure the API config for
> your gateway to support your chosen authentication methods.
>
> API Gateway validates a JWT in a performant way by using the JWT
> issuer's JSON Web Key Set (JWKS). The location of the JWKS is
> specified in the x-google-jwks_uri field of the gateway's API config.
> API Gateway caches the JWKS for five minutes and refreshes it every
> five minutes.

So, it seems that within GCP at least, we don't have to do anything, and the API Gateway will handle everything. Even though this is not a confirmation that this is how it works in AWS as well, but the fact that this is how it works in GCP, it gives me some more confidence in assuming that it must be so in AWS too.